# Get setting form wordpress customizer and display in a url

Tags: wordpress

How can I create a custom url like this :

```
www.my-wordpress-blog.com/?layout=fullwidth

www.my-wordpress-blog.com/?layout=grid

www.my-wordpress-blog.com/?layout=list
```

See Example what excepted as output,

```
http://themes.themegoods2.com/letsblog/?layout=fullwidth

http://gleedthemes.com/themes/elora/?layout=2
```

I tried looking on Google, but no "how to" tutorials show up for anything like this.

Comment: not clear with your question

Comment: So what you're trying to say is that you want your Wordpress page to have different layouts based on the URL? Based on a GET parameter at the end of it?

Comment: @Addison Question is unclear thats an issue.

Comment: @VasimVanzara I agree wholeheartedly, but I also believe that it isn't too late to salvage this question if we work with OP. Then again, it might be best to have them put in some effort? What should I even flag this as...?

Comment: Yes,we can do this.

Comment: @Addison: So what you're trying to say is that you want your Wordpress page to have different layouts based on the URL? Based on a GET parameter at the end of it? yes.

Comment: @sociopath Your example will be work with my answer please check that, http://gleedthemes.com/themes/elora/?layout=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How create custom URL**

Step:1 Login to admin panel and go to "Appreance->Menu"

Step:2 Use the Custom Links panel to add a custom link to your menu, such as a link to an external website.

Step:3 Simply type in the website URL in the URL field and the menu name in the Link Text field.

Step:4 Click the Add to Menu button when done. Use the same steps outlined previously to adjust the order of the menu item and click the Save Menu button at the top or bottom of the screen to save your changes.

Please refer following for more information,
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/wordpress-add-custom-link-menu.html#gref

**How To set Layout page**

- Add page from page menu
- Select a Right side Page attribute select a template from there.
- publish page and visit a menu from front side.

**Final Solution Suggested By [Sociopath]**

Path : wp-content/themes/yourtheme/functions.php 
add this code at the end of file.

```
if( ! function_exists( 'themename_demo_set_the_header_layout' ) ){
    /**
     * Set the demo header layout from child theme.
     * @param unknown_type $header
     * @return Ambigous <NULL, string>
     */
    function themename_demo_set_the_header_layout( $header = 'layout1' ) {  
        $header =   isset( $_GET['header'] ) ? trim( $_GET['header'] ) : null;
        // Add more checking conditions here.
        return $header;

    }   
    add_filter( 'themename_set_my_header_layout', 'themename_demo_set_the_header_layout', 10, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Ok, now i have the custom urls.
What should i do to change the layout when I visit them ?

Comment: add menu item into menu and create custom menu add label according

Comment: created theme and done same thing for sample data provide to client.

Comment: Thank you Vasim Vanzara
but is not what i want

Comment: So what you want actullay? This is your example,I have do the same.http://gleedthemes.com/themes/elora/?layout=2

Comment: I found this:
see themeflower's answer
That's what i want.

Comment: I forgot to put the url:
https://forums.envato.com/t/how-to-create-demo-sites-to-showcase-different-layouts/44730/2
see themeflower's answer That's what i want

Comment: so you get solution right?If you are not get answer please ping back to me

Comment: my blog layouts are selected from wordpress customizer

Comment: I opened functions.php. Now ?

Comment: yes, but how do i change the code to work with my theme ? :(

Comment: I use a free theme. The layouts are displayed with "get_theme_mod".

Comment: ok then please send me at this mail address.vasimmca007atgmail

Comment: you are very kind and i don't want to upset you, but i just don't want that :D (i'm very paranoid). i just need that code.

Comment: nope,Pastebin is not wordpress enviorement.okay,I think you don't want to disclose.So give me a theme name.

Comment: it will take some time, now i'm on mobile.

Comment: I sent you an email with my theme.

Comment: if you don't mind we will check this tomorrow.I have to sleep now.Thanks.

Comment: I understand you are a busy man, but i need an answer, you can help me or not ?